# Setting localhost as a Spotify redirect_uri

Tags: localhost, spotify, redirect

I've looked here on SO and I've found a few posts about redirect_uri but I can't seem to figure out *how* I use Localhost as my *redirect uri* . Hopefully anyone can explain this to me.

With kind regards,

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what is described in the [Spotify tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/), you also have to whitelist your redirect URI as explained [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/):

> Whitelist a Redirect URI
>
> In Redirect URIs enter one or more addresses
>   that you want to whitelist with Spotify. This URI enables the Spotify
>   authentication service to automatically re-launch your app every time
>   the user logs in.

To whitelist your rediret URI:
**Go to https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard -> select your application -> Edit settings -> Add Redirect URIs**

For the tutorial to work, you can add `http://localhost:8888/callback` to the whitelisted URIs

Comment: This is the only answer on SO that actually explains _how_ to whitelist a redirect URI

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the steps described in the [Spotify's Web API Beginner's Tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/), which runs a local server and uses `localhost` as part of the `redirect_uri`.

Localhost URLs are valid as `redirect_uri` and useful for development purposes, though once you make your project public you will need to switch to a URL with a custom domain or IP so the request reaches your server.

What I normally do is to set up two `redirect_uri`s, one with `localhost` and another one with a domain. Then in your code you use one or the other depending on the hostname. You can see [an example](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-dedup/blob/master/app/scripts/oauth-config.js#L8-L12).

Comment: That uses node.js. I'm a client and am using Poco. So how does their tutorial help?

Answer (score 0):

After failing to find any proper explanation on request URI, I found out that `redirect_uri` is just a URL where Spotify responds back with parameter `code` for user to access the authorized user’s account. I provided a `GET` mapping URL as a callback, and Spotify responds back with:

```
www.example.com/callback?code="code to access user account"
```

(Make sure to whitelist your callback URL.)

Answer (score 0):

The docs given in spotify are wrong
Once you hit 'Sign in with Spotify' check the networks tab and in the payload check for 'redirect_uri'. Copy and paste this uri inside your Spotify Dashboard settings for redirect uri

Hope it helps