# Spotify API auth in PHP - Invalid redirect URI

Tags: php, spotify

I'm trying to connect to the Spotify API.

I get the authorization code with:

```
<?php
$redirect_uri = 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000';
?>
<a href="https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=<?php echo $client_id;?>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<?php echo $redirect_uri; ?>&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09">Get code</a><br/><br/>
```

So far so good, I get the code. Then I try to exchange for a token with:

```
$redirect_uri = 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000';
$url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
$fields = [
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  'code' => $code,
  'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
  'client_id' => $client_id,
  'secret' =>   $secret
];
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

And I've got every variation I can imagine of http://localhost:8000 whitelisted in the Spotify dashboard:

[image]

But I get this error:

```
result: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid redirect URI"}
```

edit: What's weird is I CAN successfully link up with the implicit grant client side method, using the redirect URI http:%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000 - so I know that this is whitelisted properly. I've used this URI in the code I posted above, and get the same error. I've also used every other combination I can think of, whether that's using :%2F%2F, %3A%2F%2F, a trailing slash, a trailing %3A etc etc. Same error every time!

Any ideas?

edit2: if I use $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000'; i get a different error:

```
result: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":""}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the port?

Comment: Yep, illegal redirect uri if it's in the code, just added it to the whitelist with no effect.

Comment: Found a possible duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198071/setting-localhost-as-a-spotify-redirect-uri)

Comment: thanks, yeah I've seen that post and many others like it. But I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I imagine $redirect_uri should be the unencoded form, i.e. `$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000';`  http_build_query should be encoding it for you.

Comment: Indeed the URI shouldn't be encoded in the usage

Comment: @AaronHolland - ok thanks, I didn't know http_build_query did that. But when I use $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000' I get a different error: result: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have stopped encoding the redirect_uri, it is complaining about invalid parameters.

As per the documentation, the client_id and secret aren't meant to sent along with the other parameters, they need to be added to the headers via the Authorization header:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#2-have-your-application-request-refresh-and-access-tokens-spotify-returns-access-and-refresh-tokens

```
HEADER PARAMETER 
Authorization 
Base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key. 
The field must have the format:
Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
```

Comment: Bingo thanks! Your suggestion did solve the problem - however for future readers I'll add the following - you can actually send the the client_id and secret along with the other parameters, the doc states: "An alternative way to send the client id and secret is as request parameters (client_id and client_secret) in the POST body, instead of sending them base64-encoded in the header." My mistake was I sent it as "secret" instead of "client_secret" in the post body. Doh!